# How to increase UILabel value on every click of UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working with a UILabel and assign some string value on it, now I want to update its value every time when I click on UIButton. See me IBAction code.

```
- (IBAction)IncreasePack:(id)sender {
    int increseprice = [value intValue];
    int updateprice = [price intValue];
    NSString *newprice=    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", increseprice+updateprice];
    _TotalPrice.text = newprice;
    NSLog(@"newprice %@",newprice);
}
```

When I click button the first time, my logic executes fine. But when I tap again the code is not executed but its print every time on every click.

Comment: What is value and price? It does not make sense that log is executed but previous code is not. What about breakpoint at first line and check your values on every line?

Comment: ok sir i write wrong logic i think i need to reconnect it again

Comment: The code doesn't make any logic, the "value" and "price" variable are not updating anywhere, so how a person can expect something will increment automatically.

Comment: yes i get this, i need to increased it by the basic price and than again to add it in textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) int labelValue;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewWillAppear{
  self.labelValue = 0;
}
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
    self.labelValue++;
    [self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.labelValue]];
}
```

Comment: it print the same value boss

Comment: This code should work. There is no way it prints the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make sense. Your IBAction calculates `newprice` from `increseprice+updateprice`. If `increseprice` and `updateprice` don't change, the sum of those values won't change either.

You need an instance variable that hold the current value, and when the user clicks your button you need to add the increase value to that previous value and update the total

Instead you always say

newprice = increseprice + updateprice

Nowhere do you save the new total. Click the button again and neither increseprice update price will have changed, so newprice will still be the same value.

Comment: yes sir i need to to add it in a variable than again add value with instance varable.

Comment: how can i save a value in variable so that when i again click button i will able to add previous value with price and update it on uilabel.?

Comment: i know this is not the question is very common which i asked but i just confused in it from last day